# cannot set image on code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I´m creating a result pool, where depending on the query string, the page loads the image. I have the following object

```
<li class="labelForm"><asp:Image ID="imgImagen" runat="server" /></li>
```

on the page_load event i got:

```
string path = res == "OK" ? (Server.MapPath("~/Images/Results/OK/")) : (Server.MapPath("~/Images/Results/NO/"));

path = App_Code.FilePicker.FilePicker(path);
imgImagen.ImageUrl = path;
```

The image route is a valid one. I tested it on the browser and the explorer

> D:\Proyectos Web Forms\MyPage\MyPage\Images\Results\OK\thumbsUp2.jpg

Since the code is running on the Page_Load event (way before render event), it shouldn't be the problem, and the file route is valid. However, the browser displays a little icon of empty image.

What could I be missing?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using absolute routes, instead of a relative route. Instead of this:
    `"D:\\Proyectos Web Forms\\MyPage\\MyPage\\Images\\Results\\OK\\thumbsUp2.jpg"`

Should be this:
  `"~/Images/Results/OK/thumbsUp2.jpg"`

Answer (score 0):

when i add a local file to a url like that it usually converts it automaticaly for me to:
from:
C:/Users/Carlos/Desktop/options.gif
to 
file:///C:/Users/Carlos/Desktop/options.gif

what happens if you take the rendered path (from the "view source") and paste it directly into explorer?  i've seen IE9 put up a message saying it "blocked content" and i have to click "allow content" for it to work. Maybe that's what's happening?

----*** edit ***
oh, and i also noticed you didn't specify a filename, such as helloworld.gif   :)

Comment: Sorry, The file picker method does this for me. The result string is a double dashed route = D:\\Proyectos Web Forms\\MyPage\\MyPage\\Images\\Results\\OK\\thumbsUp2.jpg.
If i paste it on the browser it works fine

Comment: Can you paste the fully rendered <img /> tag?

Comment: actually, when I was looking on the browser info, even if IE browser showed a blank logo image, it wasn't showing any image information, Chrome, didn't show the blank image logo at all, no code either.